# Mask Extension and Logic Minimization

Tags: routing, switch

I was reading a paper (Routing Table Compaction in Ternary CAM) which reads as following :

> "The mask extension technique reduces to a logic minimization problem.
>   In the discussion, I use cube to refer to the combined single entry
>   for several prefixes, and cover to refer to the set of cubes that
>   cover all prefixes. The problem then becomes: Given a set of prefixes
>   with the same length and same route, find a minimal cover."

Though I could understand **mask extension** itself and that the above cube and cover stuff is more like knapsack problem which is also NP-complete like **circuit satisfiability** problem. However, I could not really understand how this reduction works. In other words, I wanted to get more formal approach, to show that problem of **logic minimization** is same as **mask extension**.

Any help is appreciated - Thanks.

https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Routing-Table-Compaction-in-Ternary-CAM-Liu/66fc85e9460bfe284a758bb5c4c8c070b0a9f86c

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

It's explained in the first paragraph:

> The  second  technique  exploits  TCAM hardware’s flexibility. The mask for a routing prefix stored in TCAM consists of ones (the same number of ones as the prefix length) followed by all zeros. However, TCAM allows the use of an arbitrary mask, so that the bits of ones or zeros needn’t be continuous. I call this  technique  mask  extension  because  it extends the mask to be any arbitrary combi-nation of ones and zeros.

This allows route aggregation for non-adjacent subnets to the same next hop *X* like

- 172.16.1.0/0.0.0.255 -> X
- 172.16.17.0/0.0.0.255 -> X

become

- 172.16.1.0/0.0.16.255 -> X

(note the use of wildcards here; the network mask is the binary one's complement)

Comment: It's worth noting, in the very early internet, discontiguous masks did exist in the wild. It was later codified as a practice to be avoided.

Comment: @RickyBeam I was considering pointing that out - "wild" masks seemed pretty handy but could be a *major* pain when you had to clean them up later on.

Comment: @Zac67 : Thanks for your attempt. I read that part, however as I understand logic minimization is a problem in which we want to reduce the number of variables or minterms from a Boolean function. My question is how the "any" mask property becomes logic minimization (LM). I see it to be more like knapsack problem rather than LM. Can you help me making that one to one correspondence between the two problems.

Comment: @ultimatecause That optimization simply decreases the number of parameters and thus TCAM entries - that's it. The actual problem is minimizing the search for combinable entries.